# onclick() parameter becomes object Object

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
'countyOfflineNote': function (county) {
    console.log(county);
    console.log('logged county');
    var extra = '';
    extra = '...more logic...'; 

    var message = '...some logic...';


    var title = 'Create Offline County Note for ' + county.county;
    $('body').appModal({
        appliedTo: '',
        title: title,
        type: '',
        message: 'Please enter a note for the current county status',
        submessage: '',
        template: 'simple',
        contents: message,
        cancel: "<input type='button' value='Cancel' class='button action left cancel' onclick='$EP.modules.appModal.cancel(\"" + county "\");' />",
        icon: 'info',
        callback: ''
    });

    $('#support-question').focus();
}
```

The issue I am having is with the input HTML. When we pass `county` to the `cancel()` function, I end up seeing [object Object] in my console. How do I need to change the way I'm passing my parameter?

Here is the `cancel()` function:

```
'cancel': function (county) {

    county.isOffline = !county.isOffline;
    $EP.modules.appModal.close();
}
```

Comment: You're using `county` in that string concatenation expression, so JavaScript has turned it into a string. If `county` is a global variable, you should just write it directly into the function call without the string concatenation.

Comment: @Pointy That's what I thought was going on. However, `county` is not a global variable, but is a parameter for the function encapsulating the logic for the element in my question.

Comment: Then you should establish the event handler in a different way, because it doesn't make sense to embed a JavaScript object in the middle of some HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$('body').appModal({...})` code is adding an element to DOM can you 1) remove the `onclick` handler from the input html in your `cancel` property, 2) add to this input html an id like `inputId`, and attach an event handler after the element was appended to the DOM - place this code below `$('body').appModal({...})`:

```
$('#inputId').click( function(county) {
    county.isOffline = !county.isOffline;
    $EP.modules.appModal.close();
})
```

Or rather:

```
$('#inputId').click( function() {
    county.cancel();
})
```

And add `cancel` method to your `county` object:

```
cancel = function() {
    this.isOffline = !this.isOffline;
    $EP.modules.appModal.close();
}
```

Comment: I like this, the only issue is that the `county` context is lost :(

Comment: Check an update to my answer - if you have access to your `$EP.modules.appModal` object from `county` this might work.

Comment: That's what I needed to do. I did a variation, using `on('click', function()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the county object before concatenating with that element usin [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), then you'll have your object as a string.

In your function declaration you'll need to parse that string into a object, for that you can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
'cancel': function (county) {
  county = JSON.parse(county);

  county.isOffline = !county.isOffline;
  $EP.modules.appModal.close();
}
```